# How to differentiate between TCS and CS for practitioners?

Tags: discussion, community

In the context of new proposals on Area 51, a number of people who are active there and on programming sites have (imho) demonstrated a lack of perspective on the field computer science. For them, it appears, everything not coding is theory and therefore within the scope of cstheory.SE. Needless to say this has hindered both communication and establishing of a general CS site.

Example threads:

- [Is Computer Science a duplicate of Theoretical Computer Science?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/682/is-computer-science-a-duplicate-of-theoretical-computer-science)
- [Please explain the closing of Computer Science](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/713/please-explain-the-closing-of-computer-science)
- [Should research level only sites be allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79351/should-research-level-only-sites-be-allowed)
- [Two level model (MO/Math.SE) vs one level model (SO)](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/612/two-level-model-mo-math-se-vs-one-level-model-so)
- [What problems does the two-level split solve?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/630/what-problems-does-the-two-level-split-solve)

How can we make people understand the richness of computer science?

Comment: I posted an answer to one of the post you link : http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/682/is-computer-science-a-duplicate-of-theoretical-computer-science/726#726. Of course, what I said there is only my point of view.

Comment: there's a lot of anti-cstheory sentiment, and a major desire to change our site focus. Interesting, and slightly worrying.

Comment: Actually, I am worried that people really seem to think that CS = Programming + TCS.

Comment: @Suresh, they are not that many. One of their main problems seems to be people referring to us to defend their proposals. Another one is that they have anti-elitist feelings and view us as elitist and they don't like it.

Comment: Perhaps an analogy to theoretical physics and mechanical engineering would help to prove our point? Physics are perhaps the most popularized science.

Comment: @chazisop that's what I do: TCS = string theory of CS :)

Comment: Isn't that a bit strong, Suresh? ;)